# How to debug TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE] in express?

Tags: node.js, express

I used the express framework to develop a simple node js log in application. Here is my file structure:

- bin

  - www
- node modules
- routes
- uploads
- views
- app.js

When I try to run "npm start" it shows:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:631
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('id', 'string', id);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "id" argument must be of type 
string. Received type object
```

What cause this error? How can I solve it?

Here is the error stack:

```
13 verbose stack Error: nodeauth@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "id" argument must be of type string. Received type object
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:631:11)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jiatongli/Desktop/nodeauth/app.js:13:14)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
```

Comment: Need details/snapshot of your code and modules you are using.

Comment: @SureshPrajapati

Comment: "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "express-messages": "^1.0.1",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "express-validator": "^5.3.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.1.13",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.19",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-http": "^0.3.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0"

Comment: I think I do not need to include most of the code because my project file is pretty much module + starting code from express. I did not write additional code.

Comment: What I meant is your code/function which is causing this error.

Comment: Ok, Can you shrae your stating code and complete error stack which will help in getting error causing line in your code.

Comment: Sorry for that! Why I ask this question is because I do not know which line causes this error. I searched on google, but none of the answer solve this problem

Comment: No problem :) Do you get error stack? basically a info of from where the error started, something like execution flow before that error actually occured.

Comment: Yes. I got it. It is a little bit long.  13 verbose stack Error: nodeauth@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`

Comment: As we can see, the error is definitely in the first "www" file

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add those logs as well along with your starting code?

Comment: Of course! In this case, it is much easier for you to take a look at it. Sorry for the limited details, the file is really really large.

Comment: Can you share some code of app.js around line number 13? Basically that line is generating error.

Comment: Here is the code: var upload = require(multer({ dest: './uploads' }));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190187/discussion-between-suresh-prajapati-and-rieder).

Answer (score 1):

If you declared var express = require(express) without single quote May be you got this error. Modify var express = require('express'); instead of var express = require(express);

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same error. The problem must be in your require.

I accidentally forgot to mention the path i.e.

> const ErrorHandler = require("")

Just check the terminal where the app crashes. This will give you the exact idea of which line is causing the problem. In my case, it looks like this

`at Object.<anonymous  (C:\Users\madaa\OneDrive\Desktop\MadaanFashion\backend\controller\user.js:6:22)`

So I changed my require statement to this

> const ErrorHandler = require("../utils/errorHandler")

This worked for me!